# How come taxPercentage variable is being returned as null?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

The purpose of the code below is to evaluate the tax perecentage based on a given salary, "converted_basic_pay". It seems to be working fine for all values except the last row, which has a null value for any salary bigger than 15001. However,for testing purposes I set the value of converted_basic_pay to 20000, but it's still returning null instead of the maximum tax percentage.  This is tax table in sql:

[image]

```
float taxPercentage = 0;
PreparedStatement ps6 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT TaxPercentage from payroll_system.tax_info WHERE ? BETWEEN FromSalary and ToSalary");
ps6.setInt(1, converted_basic_pay);
ResultSet rx = ps6.executeQuery();
if (rx.next()){ 

    PreparedStatement ps7 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(TaxPercentage) as maxTax, MAX(FromSalary) as maxFrom from payroll_system.tax_info"); 
    ResultSet rx1 = ps7.executeQuery(); 
    if(rx1.next()){
        float maxTax = rx1.getFloat("maxTax");
        float maxFrom = rx1.getFloat("maxFrom");
        if(converted_basic_pay>maxFrom){
            taxPercentage = maxTax;
        }
        else{
            taxPercentage =rx.getFloat("TaxPercentage");
        }
        out.println(taxPercentage);

        }           
    }
}
```

The value of converted_basic_pay is 20000. How come the last line, `out.println(taxPercentage)` is returning null value instead of 45.00?

Comment: When `ToSalary` is actually NULL then any comparison results in `UNKNOWN`. You might utilize replace it with a value out of the expected range like `BETWEEN FromSalary and COALESCE(ToSalary, 10000000000)`

Comment: check your indentation. I made some edits, but I'm not sure if it belongs where it belongs (I added a closing bracket at the end, but it could belong elsewhere)